# How to store, edit and delete data while app is running. Android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite, storage

I have created an app that uses JSON and list views to show a wide range of items. So users can basically browse at their own leisure and read detailed information about each item. Now for the past week or so I have been wanting to create a "Wish list" so users can save items to their own list a "save for later" kind of thing.

Since my app uses JSON and files that are stored in the raw folder I thought my best bet would be to write to a certain object in each item, well how wrong I was you can't edit raw files whilst the app is running making that idea useless. I then tried to write them to a file but because I am using android 18 FileWriter won't work on the device I am using the old method of writing files just wasn't working the way I expected. I then thought about copying the JSON file and adding a new object as "show": "false" and just editing the line to "true" but yeah that didn't want to work due to not being able to use FileWriter.

I then thought of choosing SQLlite. Stumbled across a way to write a database from json. Well, it writes ok, but god help you if you edit any data. For some strange reason it doesn't save the database it keeps trying to recreate it on launch and if there is any conflicts the app breaks.

So to simplify I thought why not just have a simple:

Click browse > Shows list view > Click Item > Shows detailed item

then grab the "image" and the data and store this into the sql database.

My images come from the internet and are stored in the cache file for the app. So it shouldn't be too hard to grab those images right?

Im just wondering if there are any suggestions on how you think data should be stored. I need to be able to add data and delete data whilst the app is running. This is what pointed me in the direction of sql but like I said I have had some issues with this before.

A point in the right direction would be great.

regards,

Comment: The SQLite database would be the most appropriate solution there, it seems. If you're having issues with that, you should ask specifically about that, and provide the necessary [mcve], rather than asking for general suggestions about an overall approach, which is too broad and/or primarily opinion-based.

Comment: If I was I would. I was looking for a solution that would work whilst the app was live. Create, edit and delete. So sqlite it is. As Abdul mentioned to look at Room.

Comment: I read your question as saying that you are having issues with your database attempts. Apologies if I misread that. Anyway, I was mainly pointing out that questions asking for suggestions on which approach one should use generally don't go over well.

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the JSON to a Java object using GSON. Then you can use SQLite to write the data to the database and can later update and delete the data. Using Room will be much easier.

Comment: Yeah i am using GSON to display the data and thought about doing it that way. Have not touched upon room yet. Ill have a look at it and see what I can produce.